# Inequality involving absolute value.

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on a larger proof, but for my chosen method, I need to know if the following is true:

If $b_n>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $b_n\leq b_1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then is it true that $|a_1b_1+\dots a_nb_n|\leq|a_1b_1+\dots+a_nb_1|$?

I've tried to use an induction proof and got stuck.  I'm starting to think it is not true, although I haven't found a counterexample yet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the $a_n$ involved are all nonnegative, it's true. Otherwise, not. For example, $n=2$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=-1$, $b_1=2$, $b_2=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I edited the post to reflect the fact that the $b_n$ terms are in fact all positive, but we know nothing about the $a_n$ terms.  So we can't guarantee it then?

Comment: I updated my comment before seeing your answer. Sorry if it messes up the discussion thread a bit.